# Webpack without output option

Tags: webpack, sprite

I'm using webpack for generating sprite files(.png, .less). And the plugin I'm using is generated files itself, so there is no need to use output (also entry). The trouble is that this option is required in webpack. Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?